# C# show form information in Windows 11 taskbar

Tags: c#, taskbar, windows-11

I make a simple Form that can be shown over Windows TaskBar between the last program icon and first systray icon.
That works fine in Windows 10 but not in Windows 11

Handle of Shell_TrayWnd was fine retrieve in Windows 10 and Windows 11

Some idea what change ?

Thanks in advance

Here my code :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
        
public FormTaskBar()
{
    InitializeComponent();
        
    // List all windows with extended information
    List<WindowInformation> lWinExtended = cProcWinList.GetAllWindowsExtendedInfo();

    // Search for the taskbar
    WindowInformation oTaskInfo = lWinExtended.Find(w => w.Class == "Shell_TrayWnd");
    _oTargetWnd = oTaskInfo.Handle;
    // Search for the tray icon
    _oTrayWnd = oTaskInfo.ChildWindows.Find(x => x.Class == "TrayNotifyWnd").Handle;

    cGlobal.oDebug?.Log("Shell_TrayWnd : " + _oTargetWnd);
    cGlobal.oDebug?.Log("TrayNotifyWnd : " + _oTrayWnd);
    UpdatePositions();

    // Attaches the control to the taskbar
    SafeNativeMethods.SetParent(Handle, _oTargetWnd);

    Show();
```

Comment: The taskbar was certainly redesigned in Windows 11.  Have you used a Spy app to see what the new window classes are?

Comment: Yes I try it, but I do not know what handle to choose. The window's list is huge! It tries to loop over all handle and take a screenshot of the results, but I crash Windows !

Comment: Perhaps you can try to get the geometry of each window by GetWindowRect to find likely windows.

Comment: The window with class "Shell_TrayWnd" should still be there.  Look for its children.

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is SetParent doesn't do what you think it does.

try using `SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_HWNDPARENT, _oTargetWnd);`

Comment: note that setting GWL_HWNDPARENT comes with a bunch of undocumented sideeffects.
so far i found setting topmost on the attached window messes with the target topmost status.

Comment: I confirm that SetWindowLong works on W10 not on W11